# C preprocessor commands in listings package

Tags: listings, highlighting

I am using the `listings` package, which is mostly formatting things nicely. However, it fails to syntax highlight indented preprocessor commands correctly.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=C}
\begin{lstlisting}
#if SYSTEM == SYSV
#    define HDR "sysv.h"
#if SYSTEM == SYSV
    #define HDR "sysv.h"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The first `#define` keyword is highlighted properly, but the second `#define` keyword is not highlighted at all. For old compilers, the `#` symbol had to the be first character of preprocessor commands, but modern style prefers the latter system for indentation. So, I would prefer to indent the `#` symbol.

[image]

Are there any ways I can indent this symbol and have the syntax highlighting come out correctly in the `listings` package?

Comment: The first `#define` does not seem to be highlighted.

Comment: It is not in color by default, but it is bolded. The second one is not bolded.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I had indents on every line. There should only be indents on the fourth line of the lstlisting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add `\lstset{otherkeywords={define,\# }}`, then the output should be what you are looking for:

[image]

It appears that the `#` and `if` are highlighted separately. You can see that if you attempt to use `#ifx`, then the `#` is still highlighted, but not the `ifx`. So by specifying that `define` is to be treated as a keyword, you get the desired results.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=C}
\lstset{otherkeywords={define,\# }}%

\begin{lstlisting}
#if SYSTEM == SYSV
#    define HDR "sysv.h"
#if SYSTEM == SYSV
    #define HDR "sysv.h"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. This works and my code is highlighted correctly now. 

Interestingly, you cannot define # as a keyword using morekeywords={\#}, but you can define it as a keyword using otherkeywords{\#}.